# Facebook Application Authentication Using the PHP SDK

Tags: php, facebook, authentication, facebook-php-sdk

I'm currently trying to create a canvas application for Facebook and I'm trying to get it so that the user has to verify they want to authorise the application before it runs.

I'm trying to do this with the PHP SDK but to no avail so far.

Is there a way to automatically redirect to check if a user has authenticated the app?

Thanks,
Scott

Answer (score 0):

If you request for a application authentication to facebook, and the app is already authorized by the user, the authentication window does not show again. It straight way returns a token.

Answer (score 0):

You can check this tutorial http://thinkdiff.net/facebook/graph-api-iframe-base-facebook-application-development-php-sdk-3-0/ its a nice one to get started .